# Why can't test function see my py.test fixtures?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, pytest

I have the following structure:

```
demo/
  conftest.py
  test_1.py
  test_2.py
```

with `conftest.py` content being:

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture()

def my_fixture():
print  "testing"*
```

and `test_1.py` content being:

```
def test_my_fixture(my_fixture):
    my_fixture
```

and `test_2.py` content being:

```
 import pytest

 @pytest.mark.usefixtures('my_fixture')
 def test_my_fixture():
     my_fixture
```

When executed tests with `py.test -s`, I get `NameError` for the fixture in `test_2.py` but not in `test_1.py`; why?

Here is the output:

```
================ test session starts ================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.6.4
plugins: timeout, random
collected 2 items 

test_1.py testing
.
test_2.py testing
F

===================== FAILURES ======================
__________________ test_my_fixture __________________

    def test_my_fixture():
>       my_fixture
E       NameError: global name 'my_fixture' is not defined

test_2.py:7: NameError
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pytest.mark.usefixtures` marker when you don't need to directly access the fixture object (the return value of the fixture function).

**If you need to access the fixture object, use fixture-as-function-argument (the first way in your code).**

---

The reason of the error in the second code: `my_fixture` is not defined in the function (not a local variable) or in the module (not a global variable) and it's not a builtin object; but the code is trying to access it; `NameError`.

Simply don't try to access `my_fixture`. The fixture object will be `None` because the `my_fixture` function return nothing.

Comment: Here i am using my_fixture as a general setup function to be called for all my tests where it is required. I do't require direct access to fixture object. just as  cleandir fixture in http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#using-fixtures-from-classes-modules-or-projects

Comment: @reddymr, If you declare the function with `pytest.mark.usefixtures('my_fixture')`, `my_fixture` fixture function is called as you can see in the output.

Comment: It is not called when i use @pytest.mark.usefixtures('my_fixture') as in test_2.py , but it gets called when used as parameter for test function test_my_fixture(my_fixture) as in test_1.py

Comment: @reddymr, See the output: `test_1.py testing`, `test_2.py testing`: `testing` were printed for both tests.